# Selenium Actions - jsonKeyboard and jsonMouse = null

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Can you please tell me why the values `jsonKeyboard` and `jsonMouse` of `null` and because of this my actions do not work?

When I try to get my driver like that: `driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();`

```
private static WebDriver driver;

public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (null == driver) {
            LOG.info("The driver is null. Attempt to create new instance for webdriver.");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        return driver
```

But if I try to use some wrapper for my driver and get driver like that: `driver = new AddLogsForWebDriver(DriverFactory.getDriver());`

```
    public class AddLogsForWebDriver implements WebDriver {
    
        private static final CustomLogger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger();
    
        private final WebDriver driver;
    
        public AddLogsForWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
            this.driver = driver;
        }
    
        @Override
        public void get(String url) {
            driver.get(url);
            LOG.info("The " + url + " was opened.");
        }

        @Override
        public String getCurrentUrl() {
           LOG.info("The current url was got.");
           return driver.getCurrentUrl();
        }
         ...
    }
```

After that my `Actions` don't work

[image]

Any help would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: How are you using action ? `Action` is an interface while `actions` is a class

Comment: I have method `actions.moveToElement(iconButton).build().perform();`

Comment: When u used that, does it throw any exception ?

Comment: No, I don't have any exception.

Comment: I am not clear about the problem here, I think you have a class `DriverFactory` and in that you have `getDriver()` static method. But why do you have a `private`  and `final` variable `private final WebDriver driver;` in `AddLogsForWebDriver` ? `private` and `final` both have different purpose

Comment: why "@Override" here?  You're not extending a class.  Confusing architecture to me.  Keep it simple.  Just create your own methods or wrappers for driver methods...  I don't see the need to implement the webdriver interface here.  (maybe I'm missing something...)  Any reference to json in there is going to be between the webdriver and the browser methinks...  (wire protocol)